# Correct the code

Tags: sql-server, join

Please help to correct the below code .

```
select *
from openquery(DRUPAL,
    'select o.*
     from (
       select
         max(vid),
         nid
       from content_type_irb_application_form
       group by nid
     )  i
     inner join content_type_irb_application_form  o  on o.nid = i.nid and o.vid = i.vid
  ')
```

> Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 An error occurred while preparing
> the query "select o.* from (select max(vid), nid  from
> content_type_irb_application_form group by nid)  i inner join
> content_type_irb_application_form  o  on o.nid = i.nid and o.vid =
> i.vid" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked
> server "DRUPAL".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base on limited provided information, one thing can be corrected/added. An alias to `max(vid)` becoming `max(vid) as vid`

```
select * from openquery
(DRUPAL,
 'select o.* 
  from 
    (select max(vid) as vid, nid  
     from content_type_irb_application_form 
     group by nid) i 
    inner join content_type_irb_application_form o 
       on o.nid = i.nid 
       and o.vid = i.vid')
```